# dart - how do check id/name if contains in List?

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I have a case when the user wants to add a product to the cart, before that I want to check the `id/name` product whether or not he was in the cart.

if not then I will add it to the cart, if its already there I will just do edit (adding qty and price)

I have tried using the code below:

```
   Future checkIfProductHasAdded(String uid) async {
      for (var i = 0; i < _checkoutList.length; i++) {
        print(_checkoutList[i].name);

      if (_checkoutList[i].productName == getSelectedProduct.name) {
        selectedProductCheckout(i);

        print(getSelectedProduct.name +
            "PRODUCT CHECKOUT HAS ADDED" +
            _checkoutList[i].productName);

       // await updateProductCheckout(uid);

        break;

      } else {
        print(getSelectedProduct.name + "NOT FOUND AT PRODUCT CHECKOUT");
        //await addProductToCheckout(uid);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

when I `print()` value `i` does not specify the position on the `List`, but stays in position `0`.
how to make it work?

any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, if you are getting this list from elsewhere then you have to do this. However. if you're in control of how the cart information is stored then a Map is a much better solution. Use the product SKU as the key and the value is the quantity. Lookups are much easier and faster, making checks for duplicates much, much more performant than can be done with any list.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should check if a product exists in firstWhere clause.
Something like this:

```
var product = _checkoutList.firstWhere((product) => product.productName == getSelectedProduct.name, orElse: () => null);

if (product == null) addProductToCheckout(uid);
else updateProductCheckout(uid);
```

Comment: Good its work. but then, I need to know the same product checkout position, to update it (add x1 qty & price)

Comment: like the query `for i` that I use above, when `selectedProductCheckout(i);` is executed then I can take then update the same product checkout position at that time

Comment: You have a product so you can take this product index from the list, something like this ```_checkoutList.indexOf(product)```

Answer (score 6):

This solution is the quickest :

```
final bool _productIsInList = 
    _checkoutList.any((product) => product.name == getSelectedProduct.name);
if (_productIsInList) {
   // The list contains the product
} else {
   // The list does not contain the product
}
```

Note :
If you don't need to compare IDs/names, but you just want to check if a specific item is in a list, you can use `_checkoutList.contains(item)`